# Passing scope value through function call to controller not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I've a function which deletes individual items from the array, based on the value i pass. Here's the flow:- I call a function on click of a button `deleteImage('{{image}}')` and in the controller i've function defined. Here's the function

```
$scope.deleteImage = function(image) {
     console.log(image); // Output : {{image}} instead of image url
     // code to delete items from array 
}
```

The problem here is when i checked the console, i can see the `image` value in the element attribute `ng-click="deleteImage('url_of_the_image')"`, but in controller, the `image` variable is having the value `{{image}}`. What could be the issue here ?

Comment: Show your template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not need to interpolate the value.

`ng-click="deleteImage(image)"`

should be enough to fix your issue.